# How exactly does adrenaline affect melee weapons' effect?

Tags: left-4-dead-2

It is well known that an [adrenaline shot](http://left4dead.wikia.com/wiki/Healing_items#Adrenaline_Shot) will allow you to strike faster (hence shortens the strike speed).  But does it also increase the weapon's damages ?
Since combining adrenaline and a melee weapons allows you to unlock [the "Gong Show" achievement](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/L4D2/achievements/), it seems legit to wonder: is it an effect of the speed bonus, damage bonus or both ?

Comment: The question I provided covers the answer - for your swift convenience, the [answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8559/how-do-these-heavy-instruments-compare-to-one-another/8563#8563) clarifies that, aside from the chainsaw, all weapons deal the same amount of damage, only varying by attack speed.

Comment: Damn; I saw this thread earlier, during my searches, but I really didn't understand the title, I guess, and then didn't read it.  *However*, this subject doesn't cover the ranges and adrenaline aspects...  So "exact duplicate" doesn't sound fair to me.

Comment: Hm... on the one hand, I want to say that the ranges *should* be covered in the other answer. However, the adrenaline aspect would indeed be unfair of me to exclude, so I think we can switch the focus of this question to pay more heed on that, neh? I'll be more than happy to reopen like that. As for the title - I don't blame you at all. ♪

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gong Show achievement is also affected by your health; if you are low on health you will not unlock the achievement. So it seems reasonable to assume that the mini-game simply checks for health and adrenaline, without having to conclude that adrenaline actually affects melee damage per hit.

Comment: Ah, never heard about it.  That might be THE explanation; many thanks for the information !

Answer (score -3):

I think it does increase weapon damage but as there is nowhere to check it (no weapon menu or stats menu for that)  I don't think it really matters if it does or doesn't, I don't think the developers actually intended this to be something to be worried about :)

Comment: In my opinion if adrenaline doubles a melee weapon strenght, I think it's definitely something to worry about...